# Azure kubernetes - Load balancing the application deployed across the Azure regions?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-load-balancer, azure-traffic-manager

I would be deploying the application on two different Azure kubernetes cluster across two different Azure regions.

How do I Load balance the application as it is deployed across the Azure regions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd need to use Traffic Manager or Front Door. those are the regular ways you load balance across regions in Azure.